# Migration Source YML File import date string into date and time field of content type

Tags: 8, datetime, migrations

I have a json file full of data exported from a wordpress site, one field being a string representing a date and time: "03/15/2012 14:46:19".  I would like to import that string into a date and time field of a drupal 8 content type.

I am using a Migration from Source YML file.

```
fields:
 -
  name: date
  label: 'Date'
  selector: date
```

Then in process:

```
process:
  field_press_release_date: date        # is it as easy as this?
```

Is there a special plug in I'm not seeing listed on:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins

I see format date, but couldn't get any format to work.  I have complete control over the format of the date string, I have to do some processing of data from wordpress before drupal so I can do pretty much whatever is needed, if it really is as easy as setting the date_field to the date_string from the fields list, what format does date_string need to be in?

I cannot find a simple example of importing a string into a date and time field, thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The migrate plugin that handles this is [FormatDate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21FormatDate.php/8.5.x).  It looks like you are missing the input and output date formats.  For date-only, you would do something like

```
process:
  field_date:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'm/d/Y'
    to_format: 'Y-m-d'
    source: event_date
```

and for date+time, it would look something like

```
process:
  field_datetime:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'm/d/Y H:i:s'
    to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
    source: event_time
```

When migrating into the core datetime/daterange fields, the `to_format` needs to be those strings (these were written to be generic, not just for those field types).  The `from_format` gets adjusted to your input source.  If you look at the references below, there is also a way to specify time zone.

That plugin is unit tested, so core doesn't provide any YAML example, but you may be able to glean samples from [FormatDateTest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21tests%21src%21Unit%21process%21FormatDateTest.php/class/FormatDateTest/8.5.x).

References:

- [Added FormatDate migrate process plugin](https://www.drupal.org/node/2829381)
- https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2820490
- [FormatDate migration process plugin now supports specifying of source and destination timezones](https://www.drupal.org/node/2885746)
- https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2883892